# Rails, Formtastic: checkboxes, but just allow to check ONE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, formtastic

I have a form and a group of checkboxes. But I want the user to be able to only check ONE value, never more than one.

This is what I have and it works for more than one value; it's on a has many through association. But now the clients wants to check only ONE, not more than one. I don't want to make changes to the DB or the associations because this client might change her mind later.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:community_partner_organization_ids, CommunityPartnerOrganization.order('name'), :id, :name, {}, {:class => 'checkbox'}) {|input| input.label(:class => 'checkbox') { input.check_box + input.text }} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Radio buttons, by nature, only permit the selecting of a single element, and ActionView provides a [helper](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons) just like collection_check_boxes!

Give something like this a try:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:community_partner_organization_ids, CommunityParnerOrganization.order('name'), :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your code works, it does set the Community Partner Organization in the database, but when I go to the Edit page, the Community Partner Organization I previously selected is not set by the radio button.